# SQL Time Complexity

Tags: mysql

Hai can anyone help me findout the time-complexity of following queries and correct me if i'm wrong or suggest me some other better queries for this scenario

Table1 => row count = 100 , row count after applying filter = 10;

```
select count(*) from Table1; => 100

select count(*) from Table1 where value = 10; => 10
```

Table2 => row count = 100 , row count after applying filter = 5;

```
select count(*) from Table2; => 100

select count(*) from Table2 where value = 5; => 5
```

These two table have one commo field named as "field" Table2 refers that field from Table1

```
select * from (select * from Table1 where value = 10) as tab1 , (select * from Table2 where value = 5) as tab2 where tab2.field = tab2.field;

select * from (select * from Table1 where value = 10) as tab1 left join (select * from Table1 where value = 5) as tab2 on tab2.field = tab2.field;

select * from Table1 as tab1 left join Table2 as tab2 on tab2.field = tab2.field where Table1.value = 10 and Table2.value=5;
```

From the above mentioned query which one have better time-complexity or if there any better queries than this suggest me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you sample are not clear  .. try post a real data sample and not just a part  ..  the part you name  `table1 after filte`   is relevant for a valid evaluation

Comment: There are too many moving parts here, such as indices available, selectivity, statistics, etc. Nobody is going to be able to provide the definitive answer to this, only guesses. A guess might be correct for your situation, however, but it will still be a guess with just these queries to go on.

Comment: There's an extra alternative. `select * from Table1 as tab1 inner join Table2 as tab2 on (tab2.field = tab1.field and tab2.value = 5) where tab1.value = 10`.  With a LEFT JOIN, when you add a criteria for it in the WHERE clause then it won't return the unmatched anyway, so an INNER JOIN would give the same result but maybe faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) command to understand the query.

```
EXPLAIN your-query;
```

Check this too to understand how to use it [Sitepoint article](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/)